# Shopware 6 : Reading custom ManyToMany relation as an association via productExtension

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm trying to create a custom ManyToMany relation between products and related products. (yes i know there is cross-selling entities but that's not what i'm aiming for).
So e.g. i have "Hammer"-product which has a relation to a "200 nails in one box"-product. On the listing page when the Hammer is loaded i want to load the related Nails as well and show them as a side product (just the title + image would be sufficient).

Thus I have the following classes:

- ProductExtension
- RelatedProductDefinition

```php
class ProductExtension extends EntityExtension
{
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            (new ManyToManyAssociationField(
                'relatedproducts',
                ProductDefinition::class,
                RelatedProductDefinition::class,
                'product_id',
                'related_product_id'
            ))->addFlags(new Inherited())
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return ProductDefinition::class;
    }
}
```

```php
class RelatedProductDefinition extends MappingEntityDefinition
{
    public const ENTITY_NAME = 'custom_related_product';

    public function getEntityName(): string
    {
        return self::ENTITY_NAME;
    }

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection(
            [
                (new FkField(
                    'product_id',
                    'productId',
                    ProductDefinition::class
                ))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),

                (new FkField(
                    'related_product_id',
                    'relatedProductId',
                    ProductDefinition::class
                ))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),

                (new ReferenceVersionField(
                    ProductDefinition::class,
                    'product_version_id'
                ))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),

                new ManyToOneAssociationField(
                    'product',
                    'product_id',
                    ProductDefinition::class
                ),

                new ManyToOneAssociationField(
                    'relatedProduct',
                    'related_product_id',
                    ProductDefinition::class
                ),

                new CreatedAtField()
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Besides these classes i've got the following migration:

```php
// creating the related_products table
        $sql = <<<SQL
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `custom_related_product` (
                `product_id`     BINARY(16)  NOT NULL,
                `related_product_id`    BINARY(16)  NOT NULL,
                `product_version_id`    BINARY(16)  NOT NULL,
                `created_at`            DATETIME(3) NOT NULL,
                `updated_at`            DATETIME(3) NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`, `related_product_id`, `product_version_id`),
              CONSTRAINT `fk.custom_related_product.product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`)
                REFERENCES `product` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
              CONSTRAINT `fk.custom_related_product.related_product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`related_product_id`)
                REFERENCES `product` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
        SQL;
        $connection->executeStatement($sql);

        $this->updateInheritance($connection, 'product', 'relatedproducts');
```

So basically my N:M relation table looks like this (unnecessary columns left out) :
| product_id | related_product_id |
| -----------| ------------------ |
| product A  | product B          |
| product A  | product C          |

On both the product listing page and the product detail page i want to load these related products via an association if possible. There i've subscribed to the ProductListingCriteriaEvent where i add the following association:

```php
public function onProductListingCriteriaEvent(ProductListingCriteriaEvent $event): void
    {
        $event->getCriteria()->addAssociation('relatedproducts');
    }
```

The associated data does not seem to be loaded. As i breakdown the Query i come across the following:

```sql
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(HEX(`product.relatedproducts.mapping`.`related_product_id`) SEPARATOR '||')
        FROM `custom_related_product` `product.relatedproducts.mapping`
        WHERE `product.relatedproducts.mapping`.`product_id` =
              `product`.`relatedproducts`)                                                                           as `product.relatedproducts.id_mapping`,
```

The WHERE statement seems to be wrong as I assume it shouldn't match `product`.`relatedproducts` but `product`.`id`.  When changing the query hardcoded I do get some data in the relatedproducts column on product called: "product.relatedproducts.id_mapping".
After forcing the -assumably- correct WHERE statement:
`` product.relatedproducts.mapping`.`product_id` = `product`.`relatedproducts ``.

the query seems correct but my productEntity still has no relatedproducts.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It could be, that the reverse side relation is needed, which is a little odd, since it's one and the same entity on both sides. You could try adding the reverse side association nonetheless.

```php
$collection->add(
    (new ManyToManyAssociationField(
        'relatedProducts',
        ProductDefinition::class,
        RelatedProductDefinition::class,
        'product_id',
        'related_product_id'
    ))->addFlags(new Inherited())
);
$collection->add(
    (new ManyToManyAssociationField(
        'reverseRelatedProducts',
        ProductDefinition::class,
        RelatedProductDefinition::class,
        'related_product_id',
        'product_id'
    ))->addFlags(new Inherited())
);
```

If this doesn't work though, I would honestly say save yourself the troubles and use `OneToManyAssociationField` instead. I couldn't find a single instance where there's a self-referential many-to-many relation in the core. It could be that the implementation doesn't support it.

The downside of not using many-to-many relations in the payload is the loss of convenience being able to write it like this:

```php
$payload = [
    'id' => '...',
    'relatedproducts' => [
        ['id' => '...'],
        ['id' => '...'],
        ['id' => '...'],
    ],
];
```

With `OneToManyAssociationField` you would have a "proper" entity between your products, which is less convenient to manage and persist. On the other hand you could have additional fields like `position` on the entity that acts essentially as a mapping.

```php
$payload = [
    'id' = '...',
    'relatedproducts' => [
        ['id' => '...', 'childProductId' => '...', 'position' => 1],
        ['id' => '...', 'childProductId' => '...', 'position' => 2],
        ['id' => '...', 'childProductId' => '...', 'position' => 3],
    ],
];
```

The fields in the definition of `relatedproducts` could then look like that

```php
new FieldCollection([
    (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
    (new FkField('parent_product_id', 'parentProductId', ProductDefinition::class))->addFlags(new Required()),
    (new FkField('child_product_id', 'childProductId', ProductDefinition::class))->addFlags(new Required()),
    (new ReferenceVersionField(ProductDefinition::class))->addFlags(new Required()),
    (new IntField('position', 'position'))->addFlags(new Required()),
    new ManyToOneAssociationField('parentProduct', 'parent_product_id', ProductDefinition::class, 'id', false),
    new ManyToOneAssociationField('childProduct', 'child_product_id', ProductDefinition::class, 'id', false),
])
```

And in the `EntityExtension`

```php
$collection->add(
    (new OneToManyAssociationField('relatedproducts', RelatedProductDefinition::class, 'parent_product_id'))->addFlags(new Inherited())
);
```

Comment: Hi @dneustadt. 

Adding the reversed side relation didn't work out.  
So I've created the entire RelatedProductEntity, -Collection, -Definition.  

My profiler now shows that the association seems to be loaded which is one step near my end goal:  
product-listing-route::loading::association::relatedproducts::read. 

Unfortunately my productEntity does not have the relatedproduct variable.  

Am i missing out something?

Comment: You need to get it via the the extensions of the product: `$product->getExtension('relatedproducts')` - Also to load the associated children you will have to add the association for them as well. `$criteria->addAssociation('relatedproducts.childProduct')`.